# How to find if a node is master or worker in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster

In K8s, every cluster has a set of nodes, some are master and others are worker nodes.
How can we know if a node is a master or a worker?

Answer (score 5):

In general, the easiest way to check if node is master or worker is to check if it has label `node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane` ([or before Kubernetes `v1.20`](https://v1-20.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#urgent-upgrade-notes): `node-role.kubernetes.io/master`):

Since Kubernetes `v1.20`:

```
kubectl get nodes -l 'node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane'
```

Before Kubernetes `v1.20`:

```
kubectl get nodes -l 'node-role.kubernetes.io/master'
```

To get workers we can use negation for above expressions (since Kubernetes `v1.20`):

```
kubectl get nodes -l '!node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane'
```

Before Kubernetes `v1.20`:

```
kubectl get nodes -l '!node-role.kubernetes.io/master'
```

Another approach is to use command `kubectl cluster-info` which will print IP address of the `control-plane`:

```
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://{ip-address-of-the-control-plane}:8443
```

Keep in mind that for some cloud provided solutions it may work totally different. For example, [in GKE, nodes don't have any roles by default and IP address returned by `kubectl cluster-info` is address of the API Server](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture), not listed in `kubectl get nodes` command so always remember to double-check docs provided by your Kubernetes cluster provider.

Answer (score 2):

If your cluster is part of an EKS cluster, the master node **WILL NOT** be available/presented as part of the `get nodes` command noted below

```
kubectl get nodes
```

This [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/what-is-eks.html) also has more information

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kubectl get nodes` to list all nodes. Given by the roles `control-plane` or `master` you can identify the node. `master` will be replaced with `control-plane` in future releases.

By default all other nodes without a role should be the worker nodes.

Also if you need a bit more information about your nodes you can call `kubectl get nodes -o wide`.

Comment: One more thing. Some cloud provider do not show you the master node in a managed environment (i.e. GKE). This depends on provider and setup of the kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The `node` which `api-server`, `kube-controller-management` and `kube-scheduler` running on is the `master` node.